# Extract original file content from CADES signed XML file

Tags: c#, vb.net, cryptography

first of all I say that I do not want ready code but an evaluation from those who know more than me! I'm working with XML.P7M files signed with CADES. This signature adds characters at the beginning, at the end and in the middle of the file, making it illegible. To make it readable am moment I have to extract the file by removing the contents injected by the signature. I do this with the Bouncycastle DLL.
Here is the code

```
Public Function ConvertP7MXml(ByVal filePath As String) As Boolean

    Try
        Using inputStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Dim signedFile As CmsSignedData = New CmsSignedData(inputStream)

            sFile = Application.StartupPath & "\tmpDecrFile.xml" 'Path.GetTempFileName()

            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(sFile) Then My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(sFile)
            Using fileStream = New FileStream(sFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)
                signedFile.SignedContent.Write(fileStream)
            End Using
            File.SetAttributes(sFile, FileAttributes.Hidden)
            Return True
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Corrupted P7M file or invalid file")
        Return False
    End Try


End Function
```

I would like to know if possible to do this with the Framework only classes with references to any documentation.
I apologize for the previous poorly understood message but I write poorly in English, I'm Italian!
Thanks for your attention

Comment: If your question is "Can someone help me?" the answer is either "probably" or "Sure, if you provide the code you have problems with and describe the problem you are facing". I would suggest editing your question, check the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page.

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem. If it is just signed, the content can be extracted with no problem. Signing XML files only adds a signature of the content written so others can verify it was not altered. Do you want to verify the signature? Is it not signed but encrypted?